# Enumerating Constraints in LP Model in Pulp Package

Tags: python, loops, constraints, pulp

I am creating a linear optimization model using python using the pulp package. I am wondering if there is a simple way to add constraints to a model without many hard coding every variable. For example...I am currently using a for loop to create the following set partitioning constraints:

```
for j in range(0,(len(excel_data_df))) :
    i = j * 3
    OptModel += x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2] == 1
```

This works for smaller problems. However as the variable i gets larger it becomes very time consuming to add all of the indices in the constraint.

Would it be possible to loop through all of the values which i can take and then generate the OptModel+= line of code automatically? For example if the variable i is 100 I would want the code to generate the following without having to manually add each x[i] variable.

```
 for j in range(0,(len(excel_data_df))) :
    for i in range(0,100)
       OptModel += x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + ......+ x[100] == 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lpSum` method which allows you to sum over lists of vatriables - so all you need to do is have a way of generating the indexes you want to sum over. In your second exmaple you could do:

```
OptModel += lpSum([x[i] for i in range(0, 100)]) == 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a ton!